# Does the "cast to first member of standard layout" type punning rule extend to arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

Specifically, I am wrapping a C API in a friendly C++ wrapper. The C API has this fairly standard shape:

```
struct foo {...};
void get_foos(size_t* count, foo* dst);
```

And what I'd **like** to do, is save myself an extra copy by passing a typed-punned wrapper *array* directly to the C api with a bunch of sanity checking `static_assert()`.

```
class fooWrapper {
  foo raw_;
public:
   [...]
};

std::vector<fooWrapper> get_foo_vector() {
  size_t count = 0;
  get_foos(&count, nullptr);

  std::vector<fooWrapper> result(count);

  // Is this OK?
  static_assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(fooWrapper), "");
  static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<fooWrapper>::value, "");
  get_foos(&count, reinterpret_cast<foo*>(result.data()));

  return result;
}
```

My understanding is that it is valid code, since all accessed memory locations individually qualify under the rule, but I'd like confirmation on that.

**Edit:** Obviously, as long as `reinterpret_cast<char*>(result.data() + n) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(result.data()) + n*sizeof(foo)` is true, it'll *work* under all major compilers today. But I'm wondering if the standard agrees.

Comment: Why not inherit from `foo`? Then you do not need `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: My understanding is this is fine for POD-type classes. You can use [is_pod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) to check if it's valid. In particular, a wrapper class with virtual methods wouldn't fit this criteria, even if it only had the members from struct foo.

Comment: @Hitobat Could you elaborate why it needs to be a full POD and not just a standard layout type?

Comment: I am inclined to say 'No'. I do not see mentioning of arrays in type punning, and I do not know of any bridge there. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I want this to be valid. [This section](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3) in the standard is what would allow it for single objects, but I'm not sure if there are other rules that come into effect since we are talking about an array.

Comment: @Frank I think pod guarantees interoperability with C, whereas only standard layout does not? I'm not sure the exact difference that prevents though, probably it's something to do with copy constructors.

Comment: @Hiltobat, I *think* this doesn't apply here because I perform the type punning in C++ land, and the C code only gets the C struct so there is no interoperability happening here.

Comment: Reading some more I think this is still fine. Specifically from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout), it states the reinterpret_cast is fine. "A pointer to an object of standard-layout struct type can be reinterpret_cast ...". Also if objects are layout-compatible then an array will also be fine, since they will be placed in the array in the same way.

Comment: I think this is fine. It's allowed to convert a `fooWrapper*` into a `foo*` and vice-versa, by [this part](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3) of the standard. The remaining piece is whether it's valid to say `fooPtr + n`, which would be equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<foo*>(fooWrapperPtr + n)` (it's definitely not always valid even if you can `reinterpret_cast` between `foo*` and `fooWrapper*`; consider if `sizeof(fooWrapper) > sizeof(foo)`). If it is valid, then this code is valid.

Comment: The concept "POD" is not meaningful any more in C++ *standard layout* and *trivial* are used

Comment: @Slava: sorry for the late answer. That would only have an impact if I were to use public inheritance, which would break encapsulation. And if I use private inheritance, it's functionally equivalent to what I'm doing.

Comment: The pointer arithmetic is invalid by [expr.add]p6.

Comment: @T.C. good pointer, this is tagged language-lawyer after all. I cleaned it up.

Comment: "type punning" is when you interpret f.ex. an `int` as a `float`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, this is not type punning. The `reinterpret_cast` you're doing is just an over-written way of doing `&result.data().foo_`. Type punning is accessing an object of one type through a pointer/reference to another type. You're accessing a subobject of the other type.

Second, this doesn't work. [Pointer arithmetic is based on having an array](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add) (a single object acts as an array of 1 element for the purposes of pointer arithmetic). And `vector<T>` is defined by fiat to produce an array of `T`s. But an array of `T` is not equivalent to an array of some subobject of `T`, even if that subobject is the same size as `T` and `T` is standard layout.

Therefore, if `get_foos` performs pointer arithmetic on its given array of `foo`s, that's UB. Oh sure, it will almost certainly *work*. But the language's answer is UB.

Comment: Can `std::launder` be used as a helper to make it well-defined?

Comment: Iinteresting. So the C++ pointer arithmetic rules still apply to the internals of get_foo(), even though it's part of a C library, just because the passed arguments contains objects created in the C++ machine?

Comment: @Frank: If you're passing something off to C, then that's for the C standard to deal with. The C++ standard can only speak of the nature of things within its own abstract model. Once you leave the world of C++, you're not governed by the C++ standard anymore.

Comment: What about "_The lifetime of an object of type `struct foo[]` begins when:
storage with the proper alignment and size for `struct foo[]` is obtained"_?

Comment: @curiousguy: What about it? That statement cannot be used to justify a belief that all memory everywhere contains all possible objects at all times. The object has already been created, and it was not created as an array. Therefore, it cannot magically become an array just because you believe it to be an array. This idea is not supported by the standard, as evidenced by the fact that the committee is trying to create something like this idea [right now](http://wg21.link/P0593). If they believed the standard says what you think it does, they wouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @NicolBolas The standard is very divided on many extremely fundamental issues. The idea that all potential objects exist all time in a ghost state is the cleanest approach and the only one that follows the charter of the committee, to follow existing practice and define C/C++.

Comment: @curiousguy: No, some *people* are very divided. The *standard* is very clear. Objects do not spontaneously come into existence just because it would be convenient. Arrays do not materialize around objects that happen to be in contiguous memory. And so forth. That's what the C++ object model says. Some people don't want to accept this, but wanting it to be different will not make it so. There is a difference between saying "we should change the object model to say X" and "the object model already says X". And FYI, the former ain't gonna happen.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can you clearly answer all my posted questions on SO re: pointers then?

Comment: @NicolBolas "_Therefore, it cannot magically become an array just because you believe it to be an array_" Do you believe that different objects (potentially infinitely many) existing at the same time at the same address would be an absurd idea? If so, why?

Comment: @curiousguy: Because if you believe that everything exists everywhere, you don't have a sane object model. What is legal and what is not becomes a meaningless question, because everything is legal. If memory is just memory and bytes are just bytes, then the very concept of "object" no longer matters. Invariants cannot exist or be maintained because the back doors are always open. If everything can be and is everywhere, then you've really said nothing about anywhere. An object model is about imposing restrictions on memory, not about saying "whatever".

Comment: @NicolBolas Invariants obviously exist only regarding initialized trivial objects or constructed polymorphic objects. The rest are just make believe. Many objects virtually exist at the same address has always been inherently true for union types, unless you believe that unions were not support by many C++ std versions.

Comment: @curiousguy: Look, I know how you want the C++ object model to behave, and I know how it actually behaves. These are not the same, and this conversation will not *make* them the same. If you want to have a substantive discussion about how the C++ object model ought to be, there are forums where this discussion can be had. This comment thread is not one of them. The question is tagged "language-lawyer", so only answers which describe what the standard says are valid.

Comment: @NicolBolas So tell me how unions behave, if objects are non coexisting at the same address. Are you saying that using an union is illegal? The standard is divided on many fundamental issues. It says that pointers are trivial types and then they behave in ways not trivial. The authors of the standard simply don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173235/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nicol-bolas).